How to get bus-info in a generic way
this is VM, There is no bus-info in the uevent file
~]# ethtool -i eth0 | grep bus-info
bus-info: 0000:00:03.0
~]# lshw -C net -businfo
Bus info          Device     Class          Description
=======================================================
pci@0000:00:03.0             network        Virtio network device
virtio@0          eth0       network        Ethernet interface
~]# cat /sys/class/net/eth0/device/uevent 
DRIVER=virtio_net
MODALIAS=virtio:d00000001v00001AF4

this is Physical machine
~]# lshw -C net -businfo | grep I350
pci@0000:61:00.0  eno1       network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
pci@0000:61:00.1  eno2       network        I350 Gigabit Network Connection
~]# lspci | grep I350
61:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
61:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
~]# ethtool -i eno1 | grep bus-info
bus-info: 0000:61:00.0
~]# cat /sys/class/net/eno1/device/uevent | grep PCI_SLOT_NAME
PCI_SLOT_NAME=0000:61:00.0

Is there a generic way to get bus-info without using ethtool, lshw, lspci, etc. CLI tools?
Can also try using Go or Python to get bus-info
I use various CLIs to get bus-info, but I want to get bus-info information in a more general way that does not depend on the environment. It would be better if I could get it in Go language.
I read the following questions, but I don't see a good solution.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/654820/how-to-find-pci-address-of-an-ethernet-interface
how to use ethtool_drvinfo to collect driver information for a network interface?

2024-05-21 Update
According to @junka's answer
Virtual machine
~]# realpath /sys/class/net/eth0/
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/virtio0/net/eth0

Physical machine
~]# realpath /sys/class/net/eno1/
/sys/devices/pci0000:60/0000:60:03.1/0000:61:00.0/net/eno1

The location of the PCI information viewed through the absolute path of the file is different, VM is the 4 field, PM is the 5 field. Why is this?

PCI is the address that we can use to find a device on the pci bus, and they are managed by a tree-like topology.  You can see that with lshw  . The result would be like *-pci:1 -> *-network:0

What is the design logic of the PCI tree-like topology? Is there any official document can refer to?
Like the example I updated, the tree-like topology levels of the network devices of the VM and PM are different. Is there any explanation for this?

pls search the device tree concept in kernel doc

All pci devices can be found in /sys/devices/. If you run
realpath /sys/class/net/eth0/device,
you can find that the full path is like
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/0000:03:01.0/virtio8.
So here you get the driver name virtio8 and pci slot 0000:03:01.0. The leading pci information here is the pci tree it belongs to in the topo.
For a physical nic, it just ends with the pci it is.
